# Return type is inferred incorrectly

Tags: typescript, type-inference

## Issue

```js
import { Util, Tree, Database, Client } from 'abyssal-tree';

export default class UtilStuff extends Util {
    private readonly currentTree: Tree;

    public constructor(config: {
        tree: Tree;
        branchID: string | false;
        event: symbol | string;
        args: any[];
        session: string;
        database: Database;
        client: Client;
        execBranch: (id: string, util: Util) => Promise<void>;
    }, private readonly enableDebug?: boolean) {
        super(config, enableDebug);
        this.currentTree = config.tree;
    }

    public execBranch(branchID: string) {
        this.enableDebug && console.log(`Util --> Execute Branch [ Tree: ${this.treeID}, Branch: ${this.branchID}, Session: ${this.session} ]`);
        this.branchID = branchID;
        return this.currentTree.execBranch(branchID, this);
    }
}
```

[image: error]

I *believe* that this error is **incorrect** as the return type of `this.currentTree.execBranch` is `Promise<void>` but the type is inferred as `any`.

[image: Return Type]

## Environment Used

`abyssal-tree` is a local module built from [this](https://github.com/VimHax/Abyssal/tree/d9afd6f38d9402e0101c356108c2c3972b471f5e) Github repository. Using `npm link` it is linked to a different project with the following `package.json`,

```
{
    "name": "Abyssal-Test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "tsc && node ./build/index.js",
        "build": "tsc"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^13.9.3",
        "@types/ws": "^7.2.3",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.25.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.25.0",
        "discord.js": "^12.0.2",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "eslint-config-marine": "^6.0.0",
        "typescript": "^3.8.3"
    }
}
```

The `index.ts` is the code sent under **Issue**. The `tsconfig.json` is the default one.

TSC Version - 3.8.3

[image: Editor Used]

[image: System Information]

## Attempts

Tried restarting the laptop, updating & reinstalling all the node modules of both projects, rebuilt the repo, tried building with the project with the issue with `--clean`.

Comment: The error you are getting is when it tries to infer the return value of a function that returns calls and returns itself recursively. However, your code, as posted, doesn't actually do that. But it is suspicious that you use the `execBranch` branch method name on two different objects (`Util`, and `Tree`). So, perhaps, you have not posted the version of code that has the problem? What is the inferred type of `this.currentTree` when you get this error?

Comment: It is `Abyssal.Tree` which points to the actual definition of it, https://github.com/VimHax/Abyssal/blob/d9afd6f38d9402e0101c356108c2c3972b471f5e/src/Classes/Tree.ts

Comment: Can you link to a web IDE that shows your problem (like stackblitz etc)?  It will increase your chance of getting a meaningful answer if others can quickly observe the issue without having to npm install things on their own machines.  Good luck!

Comment: I don't think I can...